# checkbox unique id conflict with script for styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

This is the style I want to achive: http://jsfiddle.net/f07t3qkn/

My current checkboxes has same id which is 'level'. There's a script below that identify the id(level) to perform certain task so I cannot have unique id.

However in the checkbox style that I want to achieve, ids are unique for each checkbox.This is being the drawback as it doesn't allow the script to function if the checkbox style achieved.

Now, how to alter the script so that it can allow unique id for checkbox for the purpose of styling as well as to perform that function.

Or is there a way for the script to identify the checkboxes, which id starting with the word 'level' instead of by a fixed id like 'level'? If can, maybe I can use id like 'level_1', 'level_2'....I'm worn out trying this..Exact code would be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

My current HTML for checkboxes

```
<ul class="box small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Primary]" id="level" class="level" value="1"><label>Primary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Upper Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="3"><label>Upper Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[University]" id="level" class="level" value="5"><label>University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Lower Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="2"><label>Lower Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Pre University]" id="level" class="level" value="4"><label>Pre University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Other]" id="level" class="level" value="6"><label>Other</label></li>                 
              </ul>
```

Script that make use of the id to perform other task

```
<script>
       $("#slider1").change(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       sendtobox(value, $("input[type=checkbox]#level").val());
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox]#level").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val());
     }
      else {
        $("th."+selectedval).remove();//controls removing from boxA

     }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. I would suggest you to use a common class.

Comment: Having same id for multiple elements is not recommended as per standards. In your case you need to use same name to get the checkbox value of selected checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, `id` attributes must be unique.

That said, you can select similar classes or id values in CSS (and jQuery) using an expression based [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

As such, if you change your `id` values to e.g. `level1`, `level2`, `level3`..you can select all matching elements in CSS using:

```
input[type=checkbox][id^=level]{

}
```

Of, in jQuery, using:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]")
```

> [attr^=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is prefixed by "value".

That said, note that expression based selectors are not as efficient as common selectors. It would generally be the recommendation to give each item which should share styling the same class, then select/style this class accordingly.

With that in mind, and given that the relevant checkboxes all have the class `level`, change

```
input[type=checkbox]#level
```

In your jQuery to:

```
input[type=checkbox].level
```

There should then be no need to the duplicate `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem:

1. In your script when you want to refer to more than one element, you should refer to a class rather than an ID, since ID should be unique per element.
2. You can add another ID to each checkbox. example: `id="level first_checkbox"`

I'm sure there are more ways, but I believe this is good enough to solve your problem.